# DAX Measure Default to MAX Date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'd like to adjust these two measures so they default to the max year in the dataset when there are no filters applied i.e. without having to click on 2017, how can I have the cards default to the values for that year (or whatever the max year would be dynamically)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a measure with this below code and just adjust the table and column names as per yours.

```
max_year_sales = 

VAR max_year = MAX(Orders[yr])

RETURN SUMX(
    FILTER(
        Orders,
        Orders[yr] = max_year
    ),
    Orders[sales]
)
```

Now add this measure as a Card in the report. Initially it will show the Sales for latest year. And after that, if you select a row in matrix, the value in Card will change accordingly. See the initial data and data after selecting a row in the Matrix in the below image-

[image]

Comment: something that confuses me is the date hierarchy - can you help me understand the difference in how these expressions get evaluated?

`CALCULATE([Total Sales],FILTER(Orders,Orders[Order Date]=MAX(Orders[Order Date])))`


`CALCULATE([Total Sales],FILTER(Orders,Orders[Order Date].[Date]=MAX(Orders[Order Date].[Date])))`


`CALCULATE([Total Sales],FILTER(Orders,Orders[Order Date].[Year]=MAX(Orders[Order Date].[Year])))`

Comment: I will check soon.

Comment: Hi @Roman, Please check row wise output of these 3 measure - 1. m1 = MAX(Orders[Order Date]) 2. m2 = MAX(Orders[Order Date].[Date]) 3. m3 = MAX(Orders[Order Date].[Year]) you will get some idea why results are differing.

Comment: Thanks @mkRabbani - this is helpful. So `MAX(Orders[Order Date])` gives me the last date for which there was an order, however adding the ".Date" gives me the last day of the calendar year regardless of whether there was an order placed or not..do I understand that correctly?

Comment: Both case you understand correct. Although I am confused why second case returning last calendar date of the MAX available year but it is. I checked, googled... But not clear about that logic yet :(